# Form Validation with reactjs and boot strap , error in className = invalid-feedback

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am doing form validation in reactjs and using bootstrap. When I use className "invalid-feedback" in javascript format, it doesn't apply and don't work. Neither font color changes and its size. Code is given below:
(#) is simply used for question-asking.

{errors.name && (<#div className="invalid-Feedback"> {errors.name} <#/div>)}

Comment: can you please show some code where you actually want to change the appearance?

Comment: <input 
              type="text" 
              className={classnames('form-control form-control-lg', 
              { 'is-invalid': errors.name } )
              } 
              placeholder="Name" 
              name="name" 
              value = {this.state.name} 
              onChange={this.onChange}
              />
      {errors.name && (<div className="invalid-Feedback"> {errors.name} </div>)}